# Order of adverbs

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Is there any specific rationale behind ordering similar adverbs? Clearly, I point out time adverbs, never and ever. I've found examples in which these two used in different orders.

> My mom will never, ever let us come to the mall again if you tell her! Look, we have ten dollars.

As in the above sentence, is it common to use comma between never and ever?

> Asked by Vulture if he ever never needed to use his performance in the Tarantino film as a pickup line...

All in all, I think the best choice is to use them in the form of **never ever**. Am I right?

Comment: _Never_ is a contraction of _not ever_; it's negative. _Ever_ is a Negative Polarity Item and therefore can't be used outside the scope of a Negative Trigger. So a positive sentence with _ever_ is ungrammatical: **I have ever been there*. But *I haven't ever been there* = *I've never been there.* So this is not about adverbs, but about negation. See the list of [NPIs and Triggers here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite right that normally the standard sequence ***never ever*** would be used (where ***ever*** is simply an optional intensifier for ***never***). But for your second example, including ***ever*** actually alters the intended meaning.

> 1: *Did you **never** [ever] need to use that pickup line?*
>    In this version, ***never*** would normally be understood to mean much the same as ***ever*** anyway...
>    *(Was there not even a single situation where you used/needed to use it?)*
>
> 2: *Did you **ever never** need to use that pickup line?*
>    Here, the unusual sequence forces us to apply a different interpretation...
>    *(Was there not even a single situation where you **didn't** [need to] use it?)*

---

Another way of looking at it is that in #1 the scope of ***never*** is *all occasions* when the addressee was trying to chat someone up. In #2, the scope is *a single "chatup" approach*.